# ng for is not printing the data

Tags: angular

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>avalibalty</th>
  </tr>    

  <tr *ngFor="let n of product">  
    <h1>hi</h1>
    <td>{{n.name}}</td>
    <td>{{n.price}}</td>
    <td>{{n.avaliablity}}</td>  
  </tr>        
</table>
```

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {

      product=[
        {
          'name' : 'mobile',
          'price': '7000',
          'avaliablity' : 'yes'
        },
        {
          'name' : 'tv',
          'price': '25000',
          'avaliablity' : 'yes'
        },
        {
          'name' : 'laptop',
          'price': '50000',
          'avaliablity' : 'yes'
        }
      ];

     }
```

ngfor is not printing the data. and getting the plain.

Comment: I don't understand why you've put your `product` property into your module. It should be declare in `app.component.ts`.

Comment: You declared the 'product' in your module, just move into your component

Comment: you could write a github project or something that providing the full source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Edit your app.component.ts and remove `product` object form appModule.ts **

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  product=[
        {
          'name' : 'mobile',
          'price': '7000',
          'avaliablity' : 'yes'
        },
        {
          'name' : 'tv',
          'price': '25000',
          'avaliablity' : 'yes'
        },
        {
          'name' : 'laptop',
          'price': '50000',
          'avaliablity' : 'yes'
        }
      ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `component.html` can only access data that is declared in your `component.ts`. So you need to move the `products` declaration into your `component.ts`.

**component.html**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>avalibalty</th>
  </tr>    

  <tr *ngFor="let n of product">  
    <td>{{n.name}}</td>
    <td>{{n.price}}</td>
    <td>{{n.avaliablity}}</td>  
  </tr>        
</table>
```

**component.ts**

```js
export class MyComponent {

  product = [
    {
      'name' : 'mobile',
      'price': '7000',
      'avaliablity' : 'yes'
    },
    {
      'name' : 'tv',
      'price': '25000',
      'avaliablity' : 'yes'
    },
    {
      'name' : 'laptop',
      'price': '50000',
      'avaliablity' : 'yes'
    }
  ];
}
```

Your app module is for configuring what code is imported into your module - it's not for declaring data that your components require.

You will need to do something about the `<h1>` that you have just placed as a direct descendant of `<tr>` too. I've removed it from my example.

Answer (score 0):

table should be in proper way look at the below code

component.html

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>avalibalty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let n of product">  
     <td><h1>hi</h1><td>
     <td>{{n.name}}</td>
     <td>{{n.price}}</td>
     <td>{{n.avaliablity}}</td>  
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit   {

  public product: any;

ngOnInit(){

  this.product=[
     {
      'name' : 'mobile',
      'price': '7000',
      'avaliablity' : 'yes'
    },
    {
      'name' : 'tv',
      'price': '25000',
      'avaliablity' : 'yes'
    },
    {
      'name' : 'laptop',
      'price': '50000',
      'avaliablity' : 'yes'
    }
  ];
 }
}
```

if you want show hi and name with in single column then you

```
<td><h1>hi</h1>{{n.name}}<td>
```